# c++ binary file add records, search and replace

Tags: c

I am working on binary files in turbo c++ 3.5 and i want to create a library program. I want to add information about books in a binary file and do functions such as: Search and replace, delete a record, and etc.

I do this functions but i have 2 problems: 1. For example when i add 6 records about books to file, BooksReport function cant show all records and for example just show 4 or 5 records and when i search records, from 5 records, for example i just found 3 or 2 records. 2.When i search and replace a word on file, all records thats before this edited record, will be deleted.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void add();
void search();

struct { 
    char name[20]; 
    char id[2]; 
    char publisher[20];} books, listbooks[100]; 

void main(){
    add();
    // search();
    getch();
}

//Add
void add(){
    FILE *pt;
    pt=fopen("books.dat","a");
    clrscr();
    printf("\t Please Enter Data for new book");
    printf("\n Please enter Name:");
    scanf("%s", &books.name );
    printf("Please enter ID:");
    scanf("%s", &books.id );
    printf("Please enter Publisher:");
    scanf("%s", &books.publisher);

    fwrite(&books, sizeof(books), 1,pt);
    fclose(pt);
}
void search(){
//Search and replace 
    pt=fopen("books.dat","w+"); 
    char replaceName[20]; 
    char searchName[20]; 
    rewind(pt); 
    found=0; 
    printf("Please enter search word \n"); 
    scanf("%s", &searchName); 
    printf("Please enter replace word \n"); 
    scanf("%s", &replaceName); 
    i=0; 
    do{ 
        i++; 
        fread(&books, sizeof(books), i,pt); 
        if(strcmp(searchName,books.name)==0){ 
            found=1; 
            strcpy(books.name,replaceName); 
            fwrite(&books, sizeof(books), i,pt); 
            break;} 
    }while(!feof(pt)); 

    clrscr(); 
    if(found==1){ 
        printf("Replace successful!"); 
    } 
    if(found==0){ 
        printf("Not Found"); 
    } 
    fclose(pt);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know why nobody answers? Because you´re using a 22 year old compiler, non-standard code, have no indentation, and...

Comment: Please help me. i am student and should be use turbo c++. what the problem in my codes?

Comment: If you want to use proper C++, it´s probably impossible to help you without using a newer software. G++/MinGW (and others) are up to date and free. About your question of the code: a) It looks like you want to make a C program, not C++. b) conio.h c) Incomplete (no main, no function heads...) d)...

Comment: No! my codes successful running on turbo c++ and just i have 2 bugs that i want to solve its. I am edit top codes and add main() function. please help me.

Comment: There's no question in this post. You code isn't going to fix itself magically, you know?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you read a book with `fread` the file pointer is already pointing to next book, calling just `fwrite` to update it is not correct.

You are anyway required to use `fseek` before switching between `fread` and `fwrite`.

To know the position where to `fseek` to you can use `index * sizeof(books)`.

Also your file should be opened using "binary mode" (flag `b`) because otherwise you are going to have problems when writing binary data that may contain `\n` characters in the uninitialized part.